# Count group by date zero result

Tags: sql-server, count, group-by

I have this SQL to get a report:

```
select 
    count(id_reg) total, 
    YEAR(fechaingreso) ano, 
    MONTH(fechaingreso) mes, 
    DAY(fechaingreso) Dia 
from 
    vw_casos_tc 
where 
    fechaingreso between '2012-12-05' and '2013-5-8' 
group by  
    DAY(fechaingreso), MONTH(fechaingreso), YEAR(fechaingreso) 
order by 
    Ano, Mes, dia
```

It works fine excepts for the DAYS that have no records when count(id_reg) = 0, this days doesn't appear on my result.

```
total   ano     mes     dia
-----------------------------
66  2012    12  13
22  2012    12  14
23  2012    12  17
```

There is no result for  (2012 12 15 and for 2012 12 16).
How can I modify my script to get this days with total = 0  ?

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: There are no results because you have **no records** with these dates, right?

Answer (score 5):

Here is a way, assuming SQL Server 2008 (though you can easily modify it for SQL Server 2005):

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATE, @EndDate DATE
SET @StartDate = '20121205'
SET @EndDate = '20130508';

WITH AllDays AS
(
    SELECT @StartDate YourDate
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY,1,YourDate)
    FROM AllDays
    WHERE DATEADD(DAY,1,YourDate) <= @EndDate
)
SELECT  A.YourDate,
        ISNULL(B.Total,0) Total
FROM AllDays A
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT  CONVERT(DATE,fechaingreso) YourDate,
                    COUNT(id_reg) Total
            FROM vw_casos_tc
            WHERE fechaingreso >= @StartDate 
              AND fechaingreso < DATEADD(DAY, 1, @EndDate)
            GROUP BY CONVERT(DATE,fechaingreso)) B
    ON A.YourDate = B.YourDate
OPTION(MAXRECURSION 0)
```